# PyPDF2: A4 to A3

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to convert a 6-page A4 PDF to a 3-page A3 PDF.
In order to do so I'm using the PyPDF2 module which works fine.

That being said for some reason, on few docs the output produced looks off:

[image: output]

In the picture the expected output is the one on the left and the output I'm actually having is the one on the right.

When I'm doing a simple Ctrl+P on the PDF and set A3 with 2 pages per sheet it works like a charm.

Where could this come from?

Comment: Looks like you didn't handle horizontal pages correctly. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called `2-up` : https://github.com/py-pdf/pdfly/blob/main/pdfly/up2.py

Comment: Use [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) instead of PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4. I am the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. We improved pypdf a lot in 2022.